# DOM not updating after changing slick-carousel's html with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

My slick carousel is defined inside the body as:

```
<div class="election-carousel">
      <?php echo Election.php::createView(); ?>
</div>
```

Items of the carousel are created using an interval ajax call but the carousel is not updating:

```
  setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../class/Election.php?createView=1',
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".election-carousel").html(html);
                },
                type: 'GET'
            });
        }, 5000);
```

I checked the page source after loading the carousel's items and it's there. I also tried .slick("unslick") then reinitialize but it doesn't work. It seems to be the DOM which is not updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing slickAdd and slickRemove each time you load data

```
setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../class/Erection.php?createView=1',
                success: function (html) {
                   $('.erection-carousel').slick('slickRemove',0); //remove elements starting with child 0
                   $('.erection-carousel').slick('slickAdd',html); //re-add new html
                },
                type: 'GET'
            });
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: "erection-carousel" LOL!